# Extracting same rows from multiple df´s and create new df

Tags: r, loops, extract, rows

I want to extract 13 rows from my data frames (different years, all equal). And then create a new data frame with only these 13 rows for each year.
Is there a way to solve it with a loop?
Or to apply it to the list of the data frames?

This works fine but I don't want to apply it for every year:

```
bezirke_abs12 <- Year_ABS3[c(1, 13, 23, 41, 60, 71, 81, 90, 102, 124, 135, 149, 164), ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use [**appropriate formatting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) and correct grammar, this time I've helped you. In addition on Stack Overflow we provide a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please edit your question accordingly, cheers.

Comment: Indeed please provide a `dput` of at least two of your data frames. Otherwise look into `lapply`, `do.call`, `rbind`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make a list of your objects, and then apply your filter over it:

```
years <- ls(pattern = "^Year")

filter.values <- c(1, 13, 23, 41, 60, 71, 81, 90, 102, 124, 135, 149, 164)
lapply(years, function(x) {
  assign(paste0(x, "_output"),  get(x)[filter.values, ], envir = globalenv())
})
```

However, I would not recommend doing something like this.

Instead you can combine your datasets into one using `data.table::rbinlist()` with `idcol` parameter.

It is much cleaner is all your data is in one tidy `data.frame` or `data.table`.

You can do something like this:

```r
library(data.table)
year.names <- ls(pattern = "^Year_\\d$")
years <- lapply(year.names, get)
names(years) <- year.names 
years <- rbindlist(years, idcol = "year")
years[, rn := 1:.N, by = year]
res <- years[rn %in% filter.values]
```

Comment: I have updated it with `data.table` example where all data is combined into one data.table, which I think is a cleaner way

Comment: @luis_west feel free to accept and vote if this worked for you